# Check if upgrades run correctly before upgrading table schema using Alembic

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I have a sample Table

```
class a(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = Column(VARCHAR(255))
```

Now I made some changes to my other tables and also added unique constraint to "username" column in the table shown above.

```
class a(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    username = Column(VARCHAR(255),unique=True)  # unique key added.
```

I run `python run.py db migrate` command and it detects all changes. No issue. 
Now I run `python run.py db upgrade`. This makes all schema changes in the database but fails at the unique constraint of the above mentioned table, because that table already have repeated data. Now I need to revert all the db changes to come back to my previous version ( i can't figure how to do it). Is there anyway to test if the all the upgrades run properly before commiting schema changes to database ? if not, please help me how to revert all the db changes.

Answer (score 0):

Alembic treats the changes in a migration as an atomic change. If the last thing in your migration fails, then the whole migration is discarded, so you are always left with a consistent database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894240/how-to-clean-up-incomplete-alembic-run

Comment: Unfortunately, mysql db allows incomplete transactions.